# The figure of speech 'It's your party ' meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative-language

What does 'It's  your party' mean as a figure of speech?
After reading the book 'Harry Potter and the Deathly hallows', one doubt remained with me.

In the chapter King's cross, there is this dialogue between Harry and Dumbledore.

> “Well, where do you think we are?” asked Harry, a little defensively.
> “My dear boy, I have no idea. This is, as they say, your party.”

Actually, this was the only thing that didn't make sense to me.What did Dumbledore mean by 'his party'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a saying that means "this is your idea/responsibility/choice"

The idea is that if you organize a party you get to pick the place, decorations and other details.

In the book, Harry chose the place where they are subconciously but it was *his choice*

Comment: Harry says he is lost, so I doubt he chose the place. The party bit is right.

Comment: He definitely knows King's Cross so I understood that as a more metaphorical "what the fork is going on"

Comment: I definitely like what the fork. :)

Comment: @lambie in that case you might like The Good Place, a series on Netflix.

Comment: I shall explore that.

Answer (score 0):

It's your party. =

applies to any situation that exists where two people are conversing and one of them says this.

In this case, Dumbledore is saying if they are lost it's because  of whatever Harry has done or is up to.

Answer (score 0):

'It's my party' is a catchphrase from the 1963 eponymous hit song by Lesley Gore, which has become an idiom of the modern English language.
The story behind its title is here:
https://www.today.com/popculture/lesley-gores-its-my-party-story-behind-song-t4291